# Design pattern - build similar objects

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I read a book about design patterns, and it give the next question for thinking:

We have some chairs, that build in the same order (first the legs, then the seat and so on..). Their shape is the only thing which different from one to other.

I think about the [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), but when I start to implement it, I discover some problems. There is a better design pattern?

Comment: Assuming your second paragraph is just an analogy and your third is actually programming related... what problems? Where did you get to in your implementation?

Comment: @DavidM: I try to create some classes: ChairA, ChairB, etc.. But I don't understand which class would be the concreteBuilder, and which the Bulder.

Comment: @AdamSh You didnt explained your problem well ,and should have included that what you have done so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Builder pattern is the way to go. *Builder* here can be an interface with *buildLegs()*, *buildSeat()* etc. Concrete Builders implement *Builder* and build a particular Shape *Chair* i.e ShapeABuilder returns ShapeAChair. ShapeAChair, ShapeBChair etc can extend Chair.